# How to map stat_function aesthetics to data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a `stat_function` layer to a plot with an aesthetic mapped to the state of some variable that identifies a set of parameters. I have manually created the two stat_function lines in the minimal working example below. That's generally what the result should look like.

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = -1:1), aes(x = x))
p + stat_function(fun = function (x) 0 + 1 * x, linetype = 'dotted') +
  stat_function(fun = function (x) 0.5 + -1 * x, linetype = 'solid')
```

[image]

My best guess at how to accomplish this is

```
params <- data.frame(
  type = c('true', 'estimate'),
  b = c(0, 0.5),
  m = c(1, -1),
  x = 0
)

linear_function <- function (x, b, m) b + m * x
p + stat_function(data = params,
                  aes(linetype = type, x = x),
                  fun = linear_function,
                  args = list(b = b, m = m))
```

This form works if I use constants like `args = list(b = 0, m = 1)`, but when I try to get the values for the parameters out of the params data frame it's unable to find those columns. Why is this not working like I expect and what's a solution?

Comment: I don't think `args` can be mapped as regular aesthetics, so an ordinary cycle is probably your best bet.

Comment: If that turns out to be true, then I'll have to post another question about how to create a legend for mappings that ggplot doesn't know about. Ugh.

Comment: I once asked a question about `stat_function` and legends, it may prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219411/stat-function-and-legends-create-plot-with-two-separate-colour-legends-mapped-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, nothing positive to add here; the fact stands: **`stat_function` does not support this functionality**.

The alternative is to either use for loops to make layers, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219411/stat-function-and-legends-create-plot-with-two-separate-colour-legends-mapped-t), or generate the grid data yourself, which is what was suggested as a closing comment to [a feature request discussion about adding this functionality](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2357).